# postgres update parent if entity / foreign key updates

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `recipes` and every `recipe` can have multiple `entries`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "recipes" (
    "ident" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "identifier" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "modified_on" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "entries" (
    "ident" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "recipe_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT
    FOREIGN KEY ("recipe_id") REFERENCES "recipes"("ident") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now when a `recipe` is updated, the following function is called and updates my timestamp:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_recipe_timestamp_proc()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW."modified_on" = now();
    PERFORM pg_notify('notify_recipes_update', CAST(NEW.ident AS text));
    RETURN NEW;   
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Now I also want my timestamp in the `recipe` *modified_on* to get updated whenever an `entry` which belongs to it is updated.

The following `trigger` is not working.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_recipes_timestamp_e ON entries;
CREATE TRIGGER update_recipes_timestamp_e BEFORE UPDATE ON entries FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_recipe_timestamp_proc();
```

**ERROR: Record "NEW" has no field "modified_on"**

Someone can give me a hint what I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_recipe_timestamp_from_entry_proc()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE recipes SET modified_on = now() WHERE ident = NEW."recipe_id";
    PERFORM pg_notify('notify_recipe_update', CAST(NEW."recipe_id" AS text));
    RETURN NEW;   
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_recipes_timestamp_e ON entries;
CREATE TRIGGER update_recipes_timestamp_e BEFORE UPDATE ON entries FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_recipe_timestamp_from_entry_proc();
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html

> "a BEFORE trigger's WHEN condition is not allowed to examine the
>   system columns of the NEW row (such as oid)..."

This should works on recipes table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_recipe_timestamp_from_entry_proc()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.modified_on := now();
   RETURN NEW;   
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

(edit: did not understand question on first time)

and then i would add after trigger into entries. Why you ask. This trigger (it is same as OP first trigger ) is in recipes table , it updates modified_on column every time row in recipes is  modified and after trigger (which calls update on recipes ) in entries table keeps its relations in order.

Comment: Thanks for your late answer, but this is not working. The issue is that you I was trying to set the value of a field that does not exist. `NEW` in a trigger is the actual record that I'm inserting or updating AND because that is occurring on the entries table. The solution is to remove that line NEW."modified_on" = now(); and instead replace it with an `UPDATE` statement that will update the `recipe` table.

Comment: hmm. would not be first time today if i'm giving almost correct answer, but this works on my test table (i serial, t timestamp, text) and it has same before trigger. only difference is that i do not use "column_name" syntax

Comment: Learning to read. You also want to update recipes when entries-table has been changed. This work only when entries is updated. I would actually do this so that entries has own trigger on update to do update on recipes rather than using same trigger on both.

Comment: `You also want to update recipes when entries-table has been changed.` exactly! and here is the solution:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/180081/129816